# Return 0 if value equals to null SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS expression like this:

```
=iif(Fields!nPeriodo.Value > CINT(replace(left(Split(Parameters!DimTiempoMes.Value,"[").GetValue(3),2),"]","")) ,NOTHING,Sum(Fields!PPMBSC_VentasPPM.Value))
```

I try to show 0 if expression equals to `null` as other answers of this question I try to `Format`  custom number property as: `#,##0`, but it just don´t work. Can someone help me how can I achieve this? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your entire expression that you are testing for null then you might need something like this..

```
=iif(
    IsNothing(
             Fields!nPeriodo.Value > CINT(replace(left(Split(Parameters!DimTiempoMes.Value,"[").GetValue(3),2),"]","")))
     ,0 ,Sum(Fields!PPMBSC_VentasPPM.Value)
    )
```